# Rails app using doorkeeper and devise : how to handle direct login and OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, doorkeeper

I have an existing app that use Devise for authentication. This app also has doorkeeper to allow third party app to get users data.

When a user log in a third party app he is redirected to a page handled by devise in my app, and after a successful login, he is redirected to the third party app.

The "doorkeeper devise login" page is just a view with a form for login, error or password lost will redirect to the normal devise view, and lose the redirection to the third party app.

How should i handle authentication in an app providing oauth and allowing user to login directly?